# How to get another pod name from it's IP?

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-dns

I have a pod that exposes a port (Server). Other pods (Clients) can communicate with it.

The server can find remote IP and port on a socket (when the client connects to it). I am looking for a way to get the client's pod name (from its IP and port).

I saw a bunch of questions/answers about getting pod names via kubectl. However, I am not sure whether I can do kubectl from within a cluster itself.

I am trying to figure out what is available for something running on the cluster. It's ok if it requires some special privileges. It's more complicated if it requires authentication.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/ Assign all the required permissions and use the api directly if you may, or just `kubectl` directly in your pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all the Pods with the [*List Pods*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#list-pod-v1-core) API operation and parse the JSON response for the [`podIP`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podstatus-v1-core) field (e.g. with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or some other JSON parsing tool) to find the JSON object of the Pod that has your desired IP address. Then, extract the [`metadata.name`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#pod-v1-core) field from this JSON object to get the name of the Pod.

You can do this by either directly using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/) (e.g. with curl) or with kubectl (e.g. `kubectl get pods -o json | jq ...`). In any case, you must include in this request the [ServiceAccount token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) of the [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#serviceaccount-v1-core) used by the Pod from which you are issuing the request (if you use the Kubernetes API directly, as a Bearer token in the `Authorization` header, and if you use kubectl with the `--token` command-line flag).

Regarding [authorisation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), you need a [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#role-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) allowing the `list` verb on the `pods` resource and a [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#rolebinding-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) that binds this Role to the ServiceAccount that your Pod is using (by default, Pods use a ServiceAccount named `default` in their namespace, but you can specify a custom ServiceAccount with the [`serviceAccountName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podspec-v1-core) field of the Pod).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever can be done via `kubectl` can be done via direct requests to the API server as well. All you need is to have proper [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) set up for your `pod`. Once you have it - you use can plenty of libraries dedicated for communication with k8s API server.